# Why does a Convolutional Autoencoder only need image dimensions for its input, but not for its output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am following this example of an autoencoder:
https://keras.io/examples/vision/autoencoder/

In it, they train the autoencoder to denoise images, which works fine.
Now, I wanted to adapt the code to instead upscale the image, by simply training it with resized, smaller images.

However, when I look at the model definition of the autoencoder itself, there only seems to be an argument for the image dimensions of its input, i.e. (28, 28), but nowhere would it allow me to specify that the output should be (14, 14):

```
input = layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

# Encoder
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(input)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same")(x)

# Decoder
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), strides=2, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), strides=2, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)

# Autoencoder
autoencoder = Model(input, x)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy")
autoencoder.summary()
```

From my understanding, the decoder performs the reverse steps as the encoder, so I would have expected an argument of (28, 28) *somewhere* in this line:

```
x = layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)
```

Why does this even work as it is, and how can I achieve my goal of having the output be (14,14)?

Answer (score 1):

The output dimensions are determined by CNN parameters such as padding, kernel size and stride. A stride of `(2,2)` will reduce your output dimensions to `(14,14)`.

Comment: Thanks, so the strides=2 argument sort of is the reverse operation for the MaxPooling2D (2,2) layer?

Comment: @busfahrer: No. Not in the implementation sense, not in the mathematical sense.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how exactly the example can work, or even maybe give an example of how to adapt this for upscaling images?